# React.JS with Babel is not triggering onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

This for me is pure madness.
Basic react.js example with babel.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.save= this.save.bind(this);
   }
   render () {
      return  (<button onClick={this.save}>collection stuff</button>);
   }

  save(ev){
     alert("stuff");
  }
}
```

`The save event is never triggered`.
All i have in my console is this:

> getEventTarget.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target'
>   of undefined

Did someone else experience this? my brain hurts right now.

Comment: there isn't an onClick event in your code.

Comment: ah it`a a type edit it right now.

Comment: that code works okay, http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/538/

Comment: Yes it works... the problem i face is that i try to use this in a shadow dom.... damnnnnn

Comment: i will dig deeper and see how react.js is working when loaded in a shadow dom.

Comment: nop it`s not the shadow doom.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like React.js and Scritaculous/Prototype.js don`t get along. 
The project had a lot of legacy code, after removing prototype everything worked.